# Reducing video BIOS boot times

Tags: boot, graphics-card, bios, grub

I've got a GeForce 1660 SUPER whose video BIOS appears to hold up the boot by ~10s every time my workstation is powered on or rebooted.

After hitting the power button, the screen will generally be blank for ~5s before this appears for another 5s:

[image]

After this, the UEFI kicks in and it's pretty quick to reach the OS.

I've looked into updating the video BIOS: [Nvidia's website](https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/17/%7E/uefi-%2F-video-bios-download) says graphics card manufacturers should supply updates. My card is made by PNY, and from what I can see, they have no updates.

Is there any way of speeding this up?

Comment: What is your computer model and OS? Are you using the latest BIOS? Is the BIOS set to scan the hardware on each boot?

Comment: @harrymc It's a custom build; the motherboard is an ASUS PRIME X570-P. It boots to GRUB. I can't see anything in the UEFI setup related to scanning for hardware, though it is set to 'fast boot'. The process I've described appears to actually be delaying the UEFI.

Answer (score 0):

Some advice:

The latest available BIOS today is
[Version 3405](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards-Components/Motherboards/All-series/PRIME-X570-P/HelpDesk_Download/)
from 2021/02/05. If that's not your version, an update might be useful (carefully).

For an ASUS motherboard, in
[this post](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/forums/gaming-pcs/8/209129/incredibly-slow-post-boot/)
the solution was to turn on the TPU switch on the motherboard
(if yours has one).

In
[this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fedora/comments/ehx4pe/psa_are_you_having_slow_boot_times_with_your/)
the problem was the USB-C driver from NVIDIA in the kernel
for supporting VR devices connected to the GPU.
The suggested fix was to black-list the driver
(your case might differ on details):

```
sudo echo "blacklist i2c_nvidia_gpu" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist_i2c-nvidia-gpu.conf
sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg
reboot
```

Comment: Flashing it seems to have shaved off a second, but as I mentioned above, this time is being spent before anything to do with the OS, so I doubt changing anything GRUB-related will help